# Modify over rows of a dataframe (purrr)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, purrr

An example df:

```
dt <- tibble::tibble(V1 = c(rep("alpha", 2), "gamma", "theta", "zeta", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "theta", "zeta"),
                       V2 = c("alpha", "gamma", "alpha", "beta", "theta", "gamma", rep("", 4)),
                       V3 = c("gamma", "theta", "zeta", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "gamma", "", "", ""),
                       V4 = c(rep("gamma", 10)),
                       V5 = c("beta", "gamma", "alpha", "beta", "theta", "", "", "", "", ""))
dt <- data.table::transpose(dt)
dt
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#> 1 alpha alpha gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta gamma theta  zeta
#> 2 alpha gamma alpha  beta theta gamma                        
#> 3 gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta gamma gamma                  
#> 4 gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma
#> 5  beta gamma alpha  beta theta
```

I need to modify each row such as: if the last value in a row is "gamma" modify it to "" until another value or if all values are "gamma" leave row as it is.

So, my desired output is:

```
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#> 1 alpha alpha gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta gamma theta  zeta
#> 2 alpha gamma alpha  beta theta                         
#> 3 gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta                   
#> 4 gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma
#> 5  beta gamma alpha  beta theta
```

Comment: It is easier to modify the columns before the tranpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this logic is not really all that extendable, you can do it in one fell swoop:

```
dt[col(dt) > max.col(dt != "gamma" & dt != "", ties="last")] <- ""
dt
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#1 alpha alpha gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta gamma theta  zeta
#2 alpha gamma alpha  beta theta                              
#3 gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta                              
#4 gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma
#5  beta gamma alpha  beta theta
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt[] <- lapply(
  dt,
  function(x) {
    if (all(x == "gamma") | tail(x[x != ""], 1) != "gamma") {
      x
    } else {
      last_ng <- max(which(!x %in% c("gamma", "")))
      x[-c(1:last_ng)] <- ""
      x
    }
  }
)


data.table::transpose(dt)


#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
# 1 alpha alpha gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta gamma theta  zeta
# 2 alpha gamma alpha  beta theta                              
# 3 gamma theta  zeta alpha  beta                              
# 4 gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma
# 5  beta gamma alpha  beta theta
```

Data

```
dt <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("alpha","alpha","gamma","theta","zeta","alpha","beta","gamma","theta","zeta"),
  V2 = c("alpha","gamma","alpha","beta","theta","gamma","","","",""),
  V3 = c("gamma","theta","zeta","alpha","beta","gamma","gamma","","",""),
  V4 = c("gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma","gamma"),
  V5 = c("beta","gamma","alpha","beta","theta","","","","","")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using regex

1. set every "blank" to NA
2. paste all elements of a row together if a
3. string contains only "gamma" then do nothing, else substitute every queue of 
       "gamma" at the end of the string with blank.
4. sperate the string to elements

code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(~if_else(.=="", NA_character_, .)) %>% 
  tidyr::unite(x, everything(), na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x = if_else(grepl("^gamma(_gamma)*$", x),
                     x,
                     sub("((_gamma)*)$", "", x))) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(x, paste0("V",1:10), fill="right")

# A tibble: 5 x 10
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9    V10  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 alpha alpha gamma theta zeta  alpha beta  gamma theta zeta 
2 alpha gamma alpha beta  theta NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 gamma theta zeta  alpha beta  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma gamma
5 beta  gamma alpha beta  theta NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```